# How to trigger a second event after the first automatically triggered event

Tags: jquery, ejs, jquery-events

I have the following code which works like this;

I get the URL parameter and I make an event so the dropdown option is automatically selected based on the URL Parameter. This event is triggered OK.

```
// getURLParameter function [....]

setTimeout(function() {
    var currencySelected = getUrlParameter('currency');
    $('#currency').val(currencySelected);
    console.log('url currency is ' + currencySelected);
}, 1500);
```

Now it follows the **second event trigger** which actually calls an ajax request to pass data to my current page based on selected option.

This one works only if I don't make the first event based on the getURLParameter. In both cases **it triggers by selecting a dropdown option manually by hand.**

```
$('#currency').on('change', function() {
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(id));
    console.log('on change triggered');
    myk = $("#currency").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/exchange_rates/" + myk,
        type: "GET",
        data: $(myk).serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(res) {
            // my success stuff
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

In case wondering how my EJS select code looks like

```
<select id="currency" name="currency" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select currency</option>
    <% for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {%>
    <option value="<%=data[i].currency%>"><%=data[i].currency%></option>
    <% } %>
</select>
```

> jQuery v2.1.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `trigger` method, for example:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var currencySelected = getUrlParameter('currency');
    $('#currency').val(currencySelected);
    console.log('url currency is ' + currencySelected);

    $('#currency').trigger("change"); // manually fire the change event

}, 1500);
```

Comment: Yes that's it, I know it's gonna work before even trying it. It was missing to manually fire the trigger event so it can get caught by the second in order event which calls the ajax request !